# Is that possible to get SAR value in android programattically? If possible than how?

Tags: android

[image]I want to get SAR(Specific absorption rate) value not by "*#07#" but i want to get with android coding.

Is that possible to get SAR value in android programattically? If possible than how?

I want to get SAR value which is  shown in image